# How to Create a Bash Script to Remove .config/nvim Based on User Input in Python

Tags: python, bash

Question: I have a simple Python script that prompts the user with a warning message. If the user responds with “yes,” I want to create a bash script that removes the .config/nvim directory. Here’s my Python script:

```
warning = input("do you like to remove .config/nvim to install nvchad: ")
print(warning)
```

I’ve searched Google and Stack Overflow, but I couldn’t find a answer on how to create the bash script part. Can someone guide me on creating the bash script to remove the `.config/nvim` directory if the user’s input is “yes”?

Comment: Why don't you want to remove it from your Python script?

Comment: What problem are you having? The script is just a couple of lines of shell script. Just open a file and write the strings.

Comment: if you can even better

Comment: i made a challenge for my self to make that project  without a book i know bash but i do not know python